# Large time difference for data to reach localhost

Tags: laravel, nginx, networking, server

In my laravel application, I am making a HTTP request to a remote server using guzzle library . However large time is required for data to reach local host.

Here is the resposne I get on browser ,
[image]

However if I run command `ping server_IP` I get roughly 175ms as average transmission time .

I also monitored my CPU usage after making requests in infinte loop, however I couldn't find much usage .

I also tried hosting my laravel application on nginx server, but I still observe around 1-1.1 seconds overhead .

What could be causing this delay and how can I reduce it ?

Answer (score 0):

There are few potential reasons.

1. Laravel is not the fastest framework. There are few hundred of files which need to be loaded on every single request. If you server doesn't have a SSD drive your performance will be terrible. I'd recommend to create a RAMDISK and serve the files from there.
2. Network latency. Open up wireshark and look at all the requests that need to be done. All them impact negatively the performance and some of them you cannot get around (DNS,...). Try to combine the CSS and JS files so that the number of requests is minimised.
3. Database connection on server side takes long time to setup, retrieves lots of data,...

Bear in mind that in most situations the latency is due to IO constraints rather than CPU usage. Moreover in test/preproduction environments where the number of requests per second that the server gets rounds to 0.

Comment: As my application is built in laravel already, I might not be able to use another framework, however let me host my application on a good server with SSD to check if that's the issue,
The database I am using is however as a block box to me, but the server the database is hosted on takes roughly 0.8 seconds as per the response I get .